# Difference Materials Link vs Copy Material to selected

Tags: materials, interface

What is the difference between selecting several objects and using "Copy material to selected" in the Materials Properties pane, versus pressing CTRL+L -> Materials?

[image]

Comment: Where exactly do you find "copy material to selected", please ? I can't see it anywhere. Are you sure it isn't provided by an addon ?

Comment: This is a good question. It seems they both do the same thing :).

Comment: No addon. On the material properties pane, click the downwards arrow on the right side, just below the '-' button for removing a material slot.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: But I still don't know if it behaves different than CTRL+L -> Materials...

Comment: They behave different if the Active object has less Material slots than the Selected object. Copy deletes all slots and add those existing in of the active object ; Link replace only the first slots, and keep the extra slots unchanged.

Comment: I did there may be are other differences that I'm not aware of

Answer (score 2):

They behave differently if the Active object has less Material slots than the Selected object:

- Copy deletes all slots and add those existing in of the active object
- Link replace only the first slots, and keep the extra slots unchanged.

Answer (score -2):

Install Material Utils Addon, select object or multiple objects, press Q and go ASSIGN MATERIAL. It's much easier than all these options..

Comment: I can't see how it would be easier, and that don't answer the question.